# Finding Currently Selected Button

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have been trying to find an aswer to this for hours. I am trying to get the button GameObject that accessed a function on one of my scripts. I just need to know which button accessed the script. Please help in UNITYSCRIPT!

Comment: First of all, how many different buttons that is accesing to script?

Comment: So you want know to what button you need to press to invoke a function?

Comment: Paste the script here to check, I believe it will be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a public string variable in the main script which will be hold the name of the button which accesed the script

```
public string clickedButtonName;
```

In buttons you are gonna add another script which will updates `clickedButtonName` variable with `GetComponent`

> Pseudo code

Button Script that will be called on Click;

```
public Gameobject yourMainScriptObject;

public void buttonClicked()
{
     yourMainScriptObject.GetComponent<YourMainScript>().clickedButtonName = gameObject.name.toString();
}
```

So when a button is clicked they will update the string value on the main script with their name.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: This solution is good enough for what I need. This will seriously cut a lot of lines out of my script. Thank you!